# Use Chrome Webrequest on the attributes of html tags to make them invisible

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On google chrome, I'd like to intercept some attributes of html tags, and do an action if the attributes has a certain value. 
For example, let's say I have a list-item which has an attribute called user:

```
<li class="MyClass" user="BadUser"> ... </li>
```

What I would like is to make the content of this item invisible, to delete it, whatever.

I'm new to those extension (I began to take a look at them in this very hour)

How can I do this?

Comment: You want a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to traverse the page's HTML and alter styles. You do not want a WebRequest call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a content script for this purpose. Declare the script (`myscript.js` in the example below) in your manifest file:

```
{
  "name": "Extension name",
  ...
  "content_scripts":
  [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Then in the `myscript.js` write required code, something like this (using jQuery, which is also injected as a content script):

```
$('[user]').each(function()
{
  $(this).removeAttr("user");
});
```

This is for deleting attribute itself. Of course, you can remove entire element calling `remove()` instead of `removeAttr()`.

Answer (score 0):

In your content script :

To remove from DOM use this

```
$('[my_tag]').remove();
```

And to play with each element you can use this:

```
$.each($('[my_tag]'), function(index, element) { 
  console.log(index + ': ' + element); 
});
```